# gdal_sieve in QGIS Python script not running?

Tags: raster, gdal, pyqgis

I have a raster that I want to filter using [gdal_sieve.py](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_sieve.html). However I'm having some problems with my syntax on the last line.

```
from qgis.core import * #importing the QGIS processing core
from qgis.utils import iface #importing the iface
import os, subprocess

subprocess.call(["gdalsieve.py", "-st", "300", "8", \ 
r"/data/final_classification.tif", \
"-of", "GTiff", r"/data/brent/LUCID/sieved.tif")]
```

> File "input", line 3
>       "-of", "GTiff" r"/data/brent/LUCID/buk.tif")] ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Try substituting `"8"` with `"-8"` (eight connectedness) in `subprocess.call`.

Comment: @AntonioFalciano and Jospeh, I did what you suggested, still the same error returns.

Comment: @brentiemapper - Perhaps it should be `"gdal_sieve.py"` and not `"gdalsieve.py"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
from qgis.core import * #importing the QGIS processing core
from qgis.utils import iface #importing the iface
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["gdal_sieve.py", "-st", "300", "-8", \ 
r"/data/final_classification.tif", \
"-of", "GTiff", r"/data/brent/LUCID/sieved.tif"])
```

1. `"gdal_sieve.py"` instead of `"gdalsieve.py"`;
2. `"-8"` in place of `"8"`;
3. `])` instead of `)]` when closing the call.

Comment: still there's an error on the last line, maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Consider the last update.

Comment: This is great much thanks! My wrong syntax is on line 3.